# Convert an image to Color object which can be added to background of a Layout

Tags: android

I am having the following requirement.

1> I have a background image(png) (containing various shades) of color with stripes.

Is there any class which is already available on Android using which I can convert the image to Color object & set on the layout as background color? 
Will the ColorMatrix class help ? I want to avoid using the image as background , as with different screen resolutions , even after having separate drawable folders , there can be cases when the background image can get stretched , giving a wrong view .

Kindly provide your inputs/sample code. If my approach is incorrect , kindly provide the correct logic.

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 0):

This is a confusing question...what kind of background image is this? If it's just a gradient, you can create one using ShaderFactory programmatically. And if it's something that doesn't have a lot of fine detail, you can just use a single image, and just have it scale to fit the screen. Rather than using the android:background attribute, a trick you can use is to wrap your layout in a FrameLayout, and add an ImageView behind the rest of your layout, with the background set as your ImageView's source. Set the scaleType to something like centerCrop, and it will scale proportionally.

Can you give an example image?

Comment: Thanks for your input . The image contains multiple shades of the same color Blue with stripes. It will be difficult to create the same effect by programming using Gradient , so thought of other approach of converting the entire image to a Color object , which can be set as Background color for rendering to a layout. I am not sure whether any Android classes are already available for not.

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. A Color object stores just a single color. You could make a LinearGradient with 0-width steps, which would give you a hard line between colors. It really wouldn't be that difficult to re-create from the sound of it.